# Move project directory from to a new machine (git)

Tags: git, migration, bitbucket

I am using an online repository (i.e. bitbucket) so my working directory was in one computer.

There is a long story where in that server I made some important commits and later it could not have internet access so I migrate the directory to another server (including the .git directory) Instead of cloning in the new server.

Now I can resume operations but I am not able to do push to the repository.. I get:

```
# git push --verbose
Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_username/project.git

conq:repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

BTW I generate and added the public key on bitbucket.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927070/git-error-conq-repository-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pushing url still points to bitbucket, even tough the repository doesn't exist on bitbucket anymore (as you migrated it from bitbucket to somewhere else). To change that url type:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://your_new_url
```

If your pushing and fetching urls are not the same, you need to insert `--push` after `set-url`

OR

If you didnt migrate the repository from one online repo to another, but instead migrated from one client to another (clients not servers!) then you may have a problem with your ssh key and/or connectivity. Check that you can connect to bitbucket (just visit their webpage). Also check that your ssh key setup works. Can the new client login to bitbucket with the ssh key it uses?

Also, as Mike Ver posted, you may have this problem: [Git error: conq: repository does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927070/git-error-conq-repository-does-not-exist)

Comment: It was the second alternative, but I was missing Start the ssh-agent and load my key and double check the url of remote "origin"

Comment: This link is useful for bitbucket users https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678